# Map Reduce: How can I get blocks from two different data sets to make them pairs

Tags: java, mapreduce

I want to create a Map function with the following operations:

Step 1:

I have 2 data sets `R` and `S`. I want to partition the two data sets into n equal-sized blocks which can be done by putting every (`R/n and S/n` )records  into one block.

After that:

Step 2:
Then every possible pair of blocks (one from R and one from S) is partitioned into a bucket at the end of Map phase so that can be taken from the Reduce Function as input with some id as key for each value pairs.
e.g will be `<id:(Sij, Ril)>`

### So my questions are:

1. How implement step 1? Is there any implemented function that I can use?

2.How can I refer specifically to these data sets in step 2 so that I can take one block from R and one from S?

Note: In main I define the two data sets like this :

```
 `FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(conf, new Path(args[0]), new Path(args[1]));`
```

Answer (score 0):

Just supply a solution,I think there is some better solutions.

As I tested in hadoop-0.20.2, at default, each Map read just one file. So just add a counter for Map phase, and output the counter as key,the context of data as value.
Then the second question will be quite easy, just output values with the same key